# Profile Creation Error: duplicate key value...user_id already exists

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-forms

I am creating a site with two types of user profiles (DoctorProfile and PatientProfile). Each extend UserProfile, which has a OneToOneField relationship with User.

While attempting to register new users via a ModelForm, I encounter the following error:

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "accounts_userprofile_user_id_key"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(38) already exists.
```

This appears to happen when the PatientProfile is created, it attempts to create a user. However, the user was already created using `User.objects.create_user()`

How can I configure this so that I can create the user only once?

Here is my (stripped down) forms.py:

```
class PatientProfileForm(ModelForm):
    supplied_email = forms.CharField(max_length=256, label="Email Address", required=True)
    supplied_password = forms.CharField(max_length=256, label="Password", required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    supplied_password_confirm = forms.CharField(max_length=256, label="Password (again)", required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    def save(self, profile_callback=None):
        master_patient_profile = MasterPatientProfile(user=User.objects.create_user(username=self.cleaned_data['supplied_email'], email=self.cleaned_data['supplied_email'], password=self.cleaned_data['supplied_password']))
        master_patient_profile.save()
```

A shortened version of models.py:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True)
    address_line_1 = models.CharField(_('Address 1'), max_length=100)
    address_line_2 = models.CharField(_('Address 2'), max_length=100, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(_('City'), max_length=50)
    state = models.CharField(_('State'), max_length=20)
    zipcode = models.CharField(_('ZIP Code'), max_length=5)

class PatientProfile(UserProfile):
    gender = models.ForeignKey(UserGender)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True)

class DoctorProfile(UserProfile):
    specialty = models.ManyToManyField(DoctorSpecialty)
    professional_statement = models.TextField()
```

**EDIT:** (based on Chris Pratt's suggestion)

The form's `save()` method now looks like this:

```
new_user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(username=self.cleaned_data['supplied_email'], email=self.cleaned_data['supplied_email'])
    if created:
        new_user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['supplied_password'])

    master_patient_profile = MasterPatientProfile(user=new_user)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `create_user`. That's purely a convenience method and is only really useful for the actual `User` creation form.

Everywhere else, you should be using `get_or_create`. The only drawback is that you can't set the password with that, so you need to do it in two steps.

```
user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(username=self.cleaned_data['supplied_email'], email=self.cleaned_data['supplied_email'])
if created:
    user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['supplied_password'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've incorporated it. However, since the user is still created by `get_or_create()`, and the profile still appears to be trying to create the user as well, I still get the duplicate key error. Do you know a way to avoid that?

Comment: The user will only get create by `get_or_create` if the supplied values, `username` and `email` don't match anything in the DB. I think your problem is elsewhere. Do you have any signals that are tied to `User` or any of your models here?

Comment: This is a new user registration form, so I expect `username` and `email` not to match anything and for a new user to be created. 

You were right about the signal: I had `post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)` in models.py, and `create_user_profile` was creating the second instance. Thanks for the help!